# Powershell - Basic Script not working Regarding Get-AdUser

Tags: powershell

I want to `Get-ADUser` and then compare that to whatever the user has inserted.

I would greatly appreciative if anyone could help me fix this.

```
$user1 = Read-Host "Enter the first username"
$GetUser = Get-ADUser -Filter {SamAccountName- eq $user1}

if ($user1 -ne $GetUser){
    Write-Host "It does not match our records. Please try again later" -ForeGroundColor Red
}
elseif ($User1 -eq $GetUser){
    Write-Host "It matches our records" -ForegroundColor Green
}
```

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! What kind of error message or unwanted result do you get?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can just test that there is a return from [`Get-ADUser`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/addsadministration/get-aduser), if there's no match nothing is returned.

I would also use `Identity` (instead of `Filter`) as it accepts both SamAccountName and DN.

> - A distinguished name
> - A GUID (objectGUID)
> - A security identifier (objectSid)
> - A SAM account name (sAMAccountName)

This simplifies your code to:

```
$user1 = Read-Host "Enter the first username"

if (Get-ADUser -Identity $user1){
    Write-Host "It matches our records" -ForegroundColor Green
}
else {
    Write-Host "It does not match our records. Please try again later" -ForeGroundColor Red
}
```

Comment: Thank you so much. I was beating my head around the bush the past hour.